# tanstack query infinity scrolling undefined error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tanstackreact-query

[image]

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Loading from "@/components/Loading";
import { StoreApiResponse, StoreType } from "@/types/dataTypes";
import { useQuery, useInfiniteQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import useIntersectionObserver from "@/hooks/useIntersectionObserver";
import Loader from "@/components/Loader";

const StoreListPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { page = "1" }: any = router.query;
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const pageRef = useIntersectionObserver(ref, {});
    const isPageEnd = !!pageRef?.isIntersecting;

    const fetchStores = async ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
        const { data } = await axios("/api/stores?page=" + pageParam, {
            params: {
                limit: 10,
                page: pageParam,
            },
        });

        return data;
    };

    const {
        data: stores,
        isFetching,
        fetchNextPage,
        isFetchingNextPage,
        hasNextPage,
        isError,
        isLoading,
        error,
    } = useInfiniteQuery({
        queryKey: ["stores"],
        queryFn: fetchStores,
        initialPageParam: 1,
        getNextPageParam: (lastPage: any) =>
            lastPage?.data && lastPage?.data?.length > 0 ? lastPage?.page + 1 : undefined,
    });

    const fetchNext = useCallback(async () => {
        const res = await fetchNextPage();
        if (res.isError) {
            console.log(res.error);
        }
    }, [fetchNextPage]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let timerId: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
        if (isPageEnd && hasNextPage) {
            timerId = setTimeout(() => {
                fetchNext();
            }, 500);
            return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
    }, [fetchNext, isPageEnd, hasNextPage]);

    if (isError) {
        return (
            <div className='w-full h-screen mx-auto pt-[10%] text-red-500 text-center font-semibold '>
                다시 시도해주세요
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className='px-4 md:max-w-4xl mx-auto py-8'>
            <ul role='list' className='divide-y divide-gray-100'>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <Loading />
                ) : (
                    stores?.pages?.map((page, index) => (
                        <React.Fragment key={index}>
                            {page.data.map((store: StoreType, index: number) => (
                                <li className='flex justify-between gap-x-6 py-5' key={index}>
                                    <div className='flex gap-x-4'>
                                        <Image
                                            src={
                                                store?.category
                                                    ? `/images/storebox/${store?.category}.png`
                                                    : "/images/storebox/default.png"
                                            }
                                            width={48}
                                            height={48}
                                            alt='이미지'
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div className='text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900'>
                                                {store?.name}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='mt-1 text-sx truncate font-semibold leading-5 text-gray-500'>
                                                {store?.storeType}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='hidden sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:items-end'>
                                        <div className='text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900'>
                                            {store?.address}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='mt-1 text-xs truncate font-semibold leading-5 text-gray-500'>
                                            {store?.phone || "제공번호 없음"} | {store?.foodCertifyName} |{" "}
                                            {store?.category}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))
                )}
            </ul>
            {(isFetching || hasNextPage || isFetchingNextPage) && <Loader />}
            <div className='w-full touch-none h-10 mb-10' ref={ref} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default StoreListPage;
```

```
{
    "name": "food-map-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.6",
        "@prisma/client": "^5.6.0",
        "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^5.6.0",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "5.7.0",
        "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.8.1",
        "@types/node": "^20",
        "@types/react": "^18",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18",
        "autoprefixer": "^10",
        "axios": "1.5.0",
        "eslint": "^8",
        "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.2",
        "next": "^14.0.2",
        "next-auth": "^4.24.5",
        "postcss": "^8",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
        "sharp": "^0.32.6",
        "splitting": "^1.0.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3",
        "typescript": "^5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prisma": "^5.6.0",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
    }
}
```

This is an error that occurs when implementing infinite scrolling. It seems to happen due to a failure in handling cases where the data is undefined initially. When the page is refreshed, the data loads correctly. I tried to address this issue by using optional chaining or try-catch syntax, but it hasn't been resolved. This error suddenly occurred one day after I had confirmed that the code was working correctly.[image]

Comment: Hello, I am experiencing the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I solved it by downgrading tanstack query (v5) to react query (v3).